# Слишком длинный код (Нужно укоротить)

Tags: javascript, angular

Слишком длинный код (Нужно укоротить)

```
(((((((this.form.get('topics') as FormArray).at(index_no) as FormGroup).get('lections') as FormArray).at(lection_inx) as FormGroup).get('tests') as FormArray).at(test_inx) as FormGroup).get('answer') as FormArray).removeAt(answer_inx)
```

Comment: ох))
ну как минимум можно разбить на переменные)
как пример)))
let topics: FormArray = this.form.get('topics');
let index_no: FormGroup = topics.at(index_no);
...
let answer: FormGroup = this.form.get('answer');
...
topics.removeAt(answer_inx)

topics.removeAt(answer_inx)

Comment: Уже решил. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается просто нужно было убрать as FormGroup ... и т.д.

```
this.topics.at(index_no).get('lections')...
```